# Execute all yaml files from different directory

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a directory I have created with several sub-tasks but I'm having trouble in making Ansible run all tasks from inside the specified directory.
The script looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:

# tasks file for desktop
  - name: "LOADING ALL TASKS FROM THE 'SUB_TASKS' DIRECTORY"
    include_vars:
      dir: sub_tasks
      extensions:
        - 'yml'
```

And this is the output:

```
plbchk main.yml --check
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not
match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [LOADING ALL TASKS FROM THE 'SUB_TASKS' DIRECTORY] *************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "ansible_included_var_files": [], "changed": false, "message": "/home/user/Documents/ansible-roles/desktop/tasks/sub_tasks/gnome_tweaks.yml must be stored as a dictionary/hash"}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I've tried all sorts of ways to make it run the sub-tasks but to no avail.

I'd like to do it this way instead of creating one big file containing all the tasks. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`include_vars` is not for including `tasks` , this is to include `vars` (as its name suggest). Also If you check the error message it says "`must be stored as a dictionary/hash`.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "ansible_included_var_files": [], "changed": false, "message": "/home/user/Documents/ansible-roles/desktop/tasks/sub_tasks/gnome_tweaks.yml must be stored as a dictionary/hash"}
```

**Solution:**

You need to use `include_task`for what you are trying. Check out [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html).

Here is a complete/minimal working example, here we are making a list of `yaml` or `yml` files present in a provided directory and then running `include_tasks` over loop for all the files.

```
---

- name: Sample playbook
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: Find all the yaml files in the directory
    find:
      paths: /home/user/Documents/ansible-roles/desktop/tasks
      patterns: '*.yaml,*.yml'
      recurse: yes
    register: file_list

  - name: show the yaml files present
    debug: msg="{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ file_list.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"

  - name: Include task list in play
    include_tasks: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ file_list.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I already tried `include_tasks` but it doesn't work, since I need to execute all the tasks within a specified folder...

Comment: check out the updated answer, I have updated .

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this was an excellent answer! Thanks a lot!